# How to alias a DNS name to hosts.docker.internal inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, dns

TL;DR: how do I get a client in my container to make an HTTPS connection to a service on the host?

I've got a service running on a VM on my local dev machine (macOS) that's serving HTTPS on port 8443; it's got a certificate for `dev.mycoolproject.com` and `dev.mycoolproject.com` has an `A` record pointing to 127.0.0.1.  So, if I run my client on my local machine and point it to `https://dev.mycoolproject.com:8443` it makes a secure connection to my local service.

I want to run my client inside a docker container and still have it connect to that local server on the host.  But obviously `dev.mycoolproject.com` pointing at 127.0.0.1 won't work, and I can't just use `/etc/hosts` to redirect it because the host's IP is dynamic.  I can reach the local server at `host.docker.internal:8443`, but I'll get TLS errors because the hostname doesn't match.

Is there any way I can get docker's DNS to map `dev.mycoolproject.com` to the host IP? I looked into running dnsmasq locally in the container but I had trouble getting it to work.

Comment: I guess it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach

Comment: I looked at that answer and I didn't find what I needed: I'm on a macOS host, so I can't use host networking, and I think I explained in my question why I can't just use `host.docker.internal`

Comment: Try this speciffic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541681/397872 @Emoses

Answer (score 10):

In a container where you might not have access to tools like `dig` or `nslookup` and don't want to install another 55MB package (like debian's dnsutils) just to get the `host.docker.internal` IP it might be better to use `getent` instead of `dig`:

```sh
getent hosts host.docker.internal | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: Good call! I was working in a debian container so `dig` was on hand. `getent` works great too.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue yesterday and came up with a workaround that adds an entry to `/etc/hosts` resolving to the the host IP.

You'll need `dig` or another DNS tool to query for the IP.

If you are running as root you can use:

```sh
echo "$(dig +short host.docker.internal) dev.mycoolproject.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

If you have sudo you can run:

```sh
echo "$(dig +short host.docker.internal) dev.mycoolproject.com" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Initially I was hoping the [`--add-host` run option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host) would allow for special docker entries in the host ip argument (like `host.docker.internal`) but unfortunately they don't.

I wanted to avoid more container configuration so I went with this. Setting up `dnsmasq` would be a more stable solution.

Comment: Brilliant! This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!